# Istio question, where is pilot-discovery command?

Tags: istio

Istio question, where is pilot-discovery command?
i can found. In istio-1.8.0 directory has no command named pilot-discovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compile the binary by myself.

```
1 download istio project.
2 make build
3 set golang proxy
4 cd out
```

You will see the binary.

Answer (score 1):

`pilot-discovery command` is command used by pilot, which is part of [istiod](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/istiod/) now.

> istiod unifies functionality that **Pilot**, Galley, Citadel and the sidecar injector previously performed, into a single binary.

You can get your istio pods with

```
kubectl get pods -n istio-system
```

Use [kubectl exec](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_exec/) to get into your istiod container with

```
kubectl exec -ti <istiod-pod-name> -c discovery -n istio-system -- /bin/bash
```

Use pilot-discovery commands as mentioned in [istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/commands/pilot-discovery/).

e.g.

```
istio-proxy@istiod-f49cbf7c7-fn5fb:/$ pilot-discovery version                 
version.BuildInfo{Version:"1.8.0", GitRevision:"c87a4c874df27e37a3e6c25fa3d1ef6279685d23", GolangVersion:"go1.15.5", BuildStatus:"Clean", GitTag:"1.8.0-rc.1"}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested in the code: https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/release-1.8/pilot/cmd/pilot-discovery/main.go